# JavaScript (Discord Oauth2) 400: Bad Request

Tags: javascript, authentication

I'm trying to make members join a server using oauth2.

Whenever I use the api/guilds/${guild}/members/${user} endpoint, I get this error

`{ message: '400: Bad Request', code: 0 }`

The code I used:

```
      let gid = '868120277077360660';
      let usid = '591950387112574988';

      fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/${gid}/members/${usid}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          access_token: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bot ${botToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          payload: {
            access_token: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          }
        })
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(async reo => console.log(reo));
```

I'm using **node-fetch** as *fetch*, in the code. I'm using NodeJS.

I tried many solutions, but none of them worked, it would be great if you can guide me through!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you updating body?

Comment: @DanielprabhakaranN No, can you guide me?

Comment: Check this.. may be it can help you on the syntax.. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT     and,    
https://medium.com/@9cv9official/what-are-get-post-put-patch-delete-a-walkthrough-with-javascripts-fetch-api-17be31755d28